# Как увеличить ширину рамки ul?

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
}

.glavnaya {
  margin-left: 700px;
}

.ishodniki {
  margin-left: 113px;
}

.vdvuhslovah {
  margin-left: 113px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="">
  <li class=""><i><a href="#" class="">Кибербезопасность</a></i></li>
  <li class="glavnaya"><a href="#" class="">Главная</a></li>
  <li class="ishodniki"><a href="#" class="">Исходники</a></li>
  <li class="vdvuhslovah"><a href="#" class="">В двух словах</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ничё не понятно, что значит "увеличить ширину рамки"?

Comment: Какую ширину в какую сторону увеличить? Ничего не понятно

Answer (score 0):

line-height с нужным от 100% - это к самой рамке, или к li тоже самое - тогда ширина рамки за счет ширины элементов.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
}
.glavnaya{
    margin-left: 700px;
}
.ishodniki{
    margin-left: 113px;
}
.vdvuhslovah{
    margin-left: 113px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;

}
ul{
    border: 1px solid black;
    line-height: 300%
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Кибербезопасность-Главная</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul class="">
        <li class=""><i><a href="#" class="">Кибербезопасность</a></i></li>
        <li class="glavnaya"><a href="#" class="">Главная</a></li>
        <li class="ishodniki"><a href="#" class="">Исходники</a></li>
        <li class="vdvuhslovah"><a href="#" class="">В двух словах</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
  border: 20px solid black;
}
```